# Symfony 3 API with Postgres 9.5 Post Request 500 Error

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony

I am send a Post Request to a Symfony 3 API which connects to a Postgres database. Out of 20 Request about 12 of them go through correctly and post data to the database. Around 8 of them kick back with a 500 error.

Any Idea what this can be? Is there a limit or a waiting period between post in a Postgres database. Or is this with out a doubt a problem with the code?

Comment: Check your log files

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @tkausl said about logs, I would use the `/app_dev.php/` debug url to use the "DEV" environment to test. Logs will have more detail in them in case you need them.

Location of dev log is:

```
var/logs/dev.log
```

The prod (production) log is in the same folder. The logs should show something. 500 error means a web server problem.